# Coldfusion Create directory on network drive

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm having trouble writing my ColdFusion 10 code. All it is a basic create a directory folder on a network drive. The page has a text box, you put in the name click next, and there ya go but for some reason I cannot find something like that online.

```
 <cfparam name="selectedDirectory" default="" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Project Directory Wizard</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>

<cfinclude template="header.cfm" />
<cfinclude template="mainarea.cfm" />

<cfset VARIABLES.directoryPath = '\\Volz\C$\test' />
<cfset VARIABLES.newDirName = 'bob' />

<form action="results.cfm" method="post">
<input type="text" name="newDirName" />
    <button type="submit">Add Directory</button>
</form>

<cfif cgi.request_method EQ "post">
    <cfif directoryExists(VARIABLES.directoryPath & '\' & form.newDirName )>
         The directory already exists.
    <cfelse>
        <cfset directoryCreate(VARIABLES.directoryPath & '\' & form.newDirName)> 
        The directory didn't exist, but it does now!"
    </cfif>
</cfif>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Please post what code you have so far.

Comment: Have you checked: https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfdirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form should look something like this:

```
<form action="results.cfm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="newDirName" />
    <button type="submit">Add Directory</button>
</form>
```

Then your form handler would have:

```
<cfif cgi.request_method EQ "post">
    <cfif directoryExists(VARIABLES.directoryPath & '\' & form.newDirName )>
         The directory already exists.
    <cfelse>
        <cfset directoryCreate(VARIABLES.directoryPath & '\' & form.newDirName)> 
        The directory didn't exist, but it does now!"
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Note there is no reason to use `<cfdump>`

Comment: I get this error. updated code.
The tag <cfif>, on line 20, column 2, requires an end tag.  
The <cfif> tag requires an end tag to nest within <cfoutput>, which began on line 2, column 2.
The CFML compiler was processing:

The body of a cfoutput tag beginning on line 2, column 2.
The body of a cfoutput tag beginning on line 2, column 2.

Comment: Code has been updated. Remove the `<cfoutput>`. You only need a `<cfoutput>` if you are outputting a variable.

Comment: Removed both. First page comes up fine, lets me put in my folder name "test123" I click create directory and I get this: 

Element DIRECTORYPATH is undefined in VARIABLES.

Answer (score 1):

To access networked drives, you need to be running ColdFusion as a user that has rights to that share.  Check your CF service setup.

Comment: It is, I have another few pages of code that creates a directory structure under a chosen folder and it works fine. But for some reason I can not code a seperate page to create just a single folder on the root of that drive.

Comment: i don't see why that wouldn't work.  could there the network permissions be different at the root level for that user?

Comment: No, that code works, but it just creates the folder called "bob" I want to give the option to the user to input there own name and it creates THAT. but everytime i run the page it just automatically creates the folder without giving the option

Comment: You aren't using the FORM scope.  Otherwise your code will always use the hard coded value in the VARIABLES scope.

Comment: you should not include the scope in the name of your input field

Comment: Im not sure I follow, dont i have to call upon the variable.newDirName so the code knows that the test I am inputing into the text field is actually the name of the folder that it is about to create?